# How can I use a for loop to create squared versions of existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am using the Hitters.csv dataset and am trying to create squared versions of existing quantitative columns using a for loop. I created a dataset of all of the quantitative columns in Hitters.csv:

```
features_df = hitters_df.drop(['Salary', 'CAtBat', 'CHits', 'CHmRun', 'CRBI', 'CRuns', 'CWalks'], axis=1)
```

I am a beginner at Python and inexperienced with loops. Here is what I have thus far:

```
for i in features_df:
    print (i**2)
```

How do I make this work? Do I need to use a dictionary?

Comment: Welcome to SO. [You should provide some information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about your datasource and DataFrame, such as `features_df.head()`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrt *"create squared versions of existing quantitative columns"*, assuming you've dropped *all* non-numeric columns, you can do:

```
features_df = features_df.apply(np.square)
# or just
features_df = features_df ** 2
```

If you *haven't dropped all non-numeric columns* and your `hitters_df` also includes columns with textual data (ie dtype is `object`), then loop over the columns while skipping errors or checking if it's a valid type. Or better yet, loop over [only the numeric columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
for column in features_df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns:
    features_df[column] = features_df[column] ** 2
```